# laravel 5.3 getting correct value in select option value

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

in my edit form select option value is not populating correct value from db.

ihave two models having one to many relationship. artist and album

this is my edit method in albumcontroller

```
 public function edit($id)
    {
        //
        $album = Album::find($id);
        $artists = Artist::all();
        return view('admin.albums.edit', compact('album', 'artists'));
    }
```

and this is the code populating select option

```
 <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="artist">Select An Artist:</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="Artist" name="artist_id">
                        @foreach($artists as $artist)
                            <option value="{{$artist->id}}">{{ $artist->name }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
```

this code is populating all the artists in the db but not selecting the matching one for that album.

Comment: You need to add code to put in the html `selected` for the value in the database results that matches the user selected one.

Comment: when i add selected it is selecting the last one the in the list , but it is not the correct artist value in the database. i want to get the correct artist to be selected

Comment: Just to make my answer more relevant to your question, will there be multiple artists for each album? Or just one artist for a given album?

Comment: one artist can have multiple albums . and album belongs to artist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit function:

```
public function edit($id)
{

    $album = Album::find($id);
    $artists = Artist::all();
    $current_artist = $album->artist()->first();
    return view('admin.albums.edit', compact('album', 'artists'));
}
```

Form:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="artist">Select An Artist:</label>
<select class="form-control" id="Artist" name="artist_id">
    @foreach($artists as $artist)
        <option value="{{$artist->id}}"@if($artist->id == $current_artist->id) selected='selected' @endif>{{ $artist->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: the relation is one artist can have multiple albums,  and one album belongs to artist

Comment: Yes, then my line of code will select the artist who has the album

Comment: yeah that is true, but other artists are invisible, becuase the is edit form if i want to update the artist who has this album, other artists are not populating.

Answer (score 0):

```
$album = Album::find($id);
$artist = $album->artist()->first();
$artist_id = $artist ? $artist->id : 0;
$artists = Artist::all();

return view('admin.albums.edit', compact('artist_id', 'artists'));
```

and

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="artist">Select An Artist:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="Artist" name="artist_id">
        @foreach($artists as $artist)
            <option {{ $artist_id === $artist->id ? 'selected' : '' }} value="{{$artist->id}}">{{ $artist->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```